# SQL WHERE - Column (value) does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I'm attempting to do the most basic WHERE statement in psql and I'm getting a strange error:

```
ERROR:  column "rom_tut" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname="rom_tut";
```

Why is it complaining that the value isn't a column?

Comment: Hint:  Single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use single quote for string value because double quote means column name

```
SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='rom_tut'
```

Comment: I can't believe I've used SQL for this long and never knew that! Thanks